# How can I make responsive image take up 100% of its parent's height?

Tags: css, responsive-design, image-scaling

I have this HTML:

```
<article>
    <div class="article-img">
        <img src="http://ebr4q1yu566j250m.zippykid.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/astronaut.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="article-details">
        <h2>Article Title Goes Here</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis distinctio tenetur laboriosam consectetur esse facilis quasi alias aspernatur neque ut quae necessitatibus reprehenderit laborum dignissimos repudiandae dolorum numquam magni vero.</p>
    </div>
</article>
```

And this CSS:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body { width: 90%; max-width: 50em; }
img { max-width: 100%; }
article { overflow: hidden; border: 1px solid black; margin: 1em; }
.article-details { padding: 1.1em; }

@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
    .article-img { 
        float: left;
        width: 33%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .article-details {
        float: right;
        width: 60%;
    }
}
```

When I the screen size hits 40em, the pic floats left. I want it to take up 100% of the height of the article. However, as you can see in this fiddle, there's always a little gap between the bottom of the image and the bottom of the article: http://jsfiddle.net/u7yr8cv1/

Why does this happen, and how can I fix? Thank you!

Comment: Setting both height and width will mean that the image will not hold it's aspect ratio. It that ok for your needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the default behavior of the image. There is about a 2px gap under the image for the letter descenders/the image lines up with the baseline of the text. This is because an image is inline by default.

One quick fix is to change the image to **`display:block;`**. Another solution is to use `vertical-align: bottom;`, as demonstrated in this easy article: http://salman-w.blogspot.com/2012/10/remove-space-below-images-and-inline-block-elements.html

Examples:

```
img {max-width:100%; display:block;}

img {max-width:100%; vertical-align:bottom;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a vertical alignment issue. modify your css as follows:

> `* { margin: 0; padding: 0; vertical-align:top;  }`

See:
http://jsfiddle.net/ry7jLfm9/2/

Let me know how that goes for you.

Cheers

Comment: This doesn't solve anything. He asked for the image to fill the height of the article, this simply aligns them both to the top of their containers.

Comment: yes and in doing so, fixes the issue as per the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you really want the image to have `height: 100%` and `width: 33%`, the following will do just that:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body { width: 90%; max-width: 50em; }
img { max-width: 100%; }
article {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black; margin: 1em;
  position: relative;
}
.article-details { padding: 1.1em; }

@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .article-img { 
    width: 33%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  .article-img img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
  .article-details {
      float: right;
      width: 60%;
  }
}
```